# Several questions about TFS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

Hello
I'm new to Microsoft Team Foundation Server. I just installed a basic config on my home pc to work with my colleagues on part time projects. 
The first thing I couldn't come up with is how to add existing sql server's database to source control? It works quite well for source files, but couldn't manage to work it with database too. Is there a solution?
The next question is: In team queries, I see Iteration 1, Iteration 2 and so on. What does this mean? what's those iterations and how/why should I use it?

p.S. I'm using VS 2010 and TFS 2010

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean "to add sql server database to source control"? Add entire database or just the scripts? I don't think that adding active db file is supported and honestly don't see much of a purpose...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterations are a way of dividing up the work - you might think in phases instead. You can name them whatever you like. So a particular work item might be planned for "phase 3" or "the February release". Then you can set up some queries that just show the current iteration, and you won't be overwhelmed by a lot of work items. This works really well when looking at closed ones, since you can answer "what did we do in this iteration?" (or phase.)

Comment: Thansk for the answer Kate. Could you also tell me what's backlog please?

Comment: There are two types of backlogs in scrum - product backlog and sprint (phase) backlog which are the list of work items that need to be addressed

Answer (score 4):

**Database Management** 
Visual Studio Premium and above has Database Deployment and Change Management.  These allow you to directly develop, refactor, schema & data compare, deploy and source control SQL Server 2005 and 2008 databases.  You can also target Oracle databases with the Quest Toad Extensions for Visual Studio, but I have little experience there.

Since you have access to TFS, it is likely you have access to Premium as well.  If not, take a look at the [Bizspark program](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark).

**Iterations**
Backlog is an Agile Scrum term (http://www.scrum.org/).  It's essentially a prioritized list of needs or problems to be solved for the user.